# getUserMedia and mediarecorder in html

Tags: html, mediarecorder, getusermedia

I record audio via getUserMedia and mediarecorder:

```
 ...
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(mediaStream => {
      try {            
        const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream);
        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = vm.mediaDataAvailable;
        mediaRecorder.start(1000);
        ...
```

When I receive the chucks in the callback, I send them to a web api via websockets, which simply writes the parts one after another to a file:

```
 mediaDataAvailable(e) {
 if (!event.data || event.data.size === 0)
 {
   return;
 }

 vm.websocket.SendBlob(e.data);
 ...
```

The file, which is created on the webserver side in the webapi (lets call it "server.webm"), does not work correct. More exactly: It plays the first n seconds (n is the time I chose for the start command), the it stops. This means, the first chunk is transferred correctly, but it seams that adding the 2nd, 3rd, ... chuck together to a file does not work. If I push the chuncks in the web page on an array and the to a file, the resulting file (lets call it "client.webm") is working the whole recording duration.
Creating file on web client side:

```
mediaDataAvailable(e) {
 if (!event.data || event.data.size === 0)
 {
   return;
 }
 vm.chuncks.push(e.data);

 ...

 stopCapturing() {
   var blob = new Blob(this.chuncks, {type: 'audio/webm'});
   var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   var a = document.createElement('a');
   a.style.display = 'none';
   a.href = url;
   a.download = 'client.webm';
   document.body.appendChild(a);
   a.click();
```

I compared the files client.webm and server.webm. They are quite similar, but there are certain parts in the server.webm which are not in the client.webm.

Anybody any ideas? Server code looks like the following:

```
 private async Task Echo( HttpContext con, WebSocket webSocket)
    {
        System.IO.BinaryWriter Writer = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"server.webm"));


        var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
        WebSocketReceiveResult result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
        while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
        {                
            Writer.Write(buffer);
            Writer.Flush();



            await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, result.Count), result.MessageType, result.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);

            result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
        }
        await webSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value, result.CloseStatusDescription, CancellationToken.None);
        Writer.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

resolved, I write all bytes of the reserved byte array to file in server code, not the count of received bytes.